# Stripe JS with React - could not find elements context

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm trying to use Stripe with React using React components, but however I structure the code, I keep running into the error "Could not find Elements context".

Am I missing anything obvious in the following code?

The 'ModelSubscriptionForm' component contains the 'CardNumberElement' Stripe component.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { ModalSubscriptionForm } from "./ModalSubscriptionForm";
import { exposeComponent } from "../../utils/webpack";
import { Elements, ElementsConsumer } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { loadStripe, Stripe, StripeElements } from "@stripe/stripe-js";

interface ModalSubscriptionButtonProps {
    buttonText: string;
    stripeApiKey: string;
    stripe?: Stripe | null;
    elements?: StripeElements | null;
}

interface ModalSubscriptionButtonState {
    isModalFormOpen: boolean;
}

export class _ModalSubscriptionButton extends React.Component<ModalSubscriptionButtonProps, ModalSubscriptionButtonState>  {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isModalFormOpen: false
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <a className="button f5-ns ph4-ns mb3" onClick={() => this.setState({ isModalFormOpen: true })}>{this.props.buttonText}</a>
                {this.state.isModalFormOpen && (
                    <ModalSubscriptionForm
                        isOpen={true}
                        onRequestClose={() => this.setState({ isModalFormOpen: false })}
                        stripe={this.props.stripe}
                        elements={this.props.elements}
                    />
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const InjectedModalSubscriptionButton = (props: ModalSubscriptionButtonProps) => {
    return (
        <ElementsConsumer>
            {({ stripe, elements }) => (
                <_ModalSubscriptionButton {...props} stripe={stripe} elements={elements} />
            )}
        </ElementsConsumer>
    )
}

const stripePromise = loadStripe("pk_test_1234");

export const ModalSubscriptionButton = (props: ModalSubscriptionButtonProps) => {
    return (
        <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
            <InjectedModalSubscriptionButton {...props} />
        </Elements>
    )
}

export default ModalSubscriptionButton;

exposeComponent(ModalSubscriptionButton, "ModalSubscriptionButton");
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to narrow down where this is coming from? A few points to consider:

1/ You've got `props: ModalSubscriptionButtonProps` as args for `InjectedModalSubscriptionButton` but this includes `stripe` and `elements` but then you use those from the `ElementsConsumer`. Are you certain the expected values are being used here?

2/ Since the `_ModalSubscriptionButton`  doesn't actually need stripe/elements, I'd suggest refactoring to wrap only `ModalSubscriptionForm` in the `ElementsConsumer` (and not the Button). This would allow you to separate the props a bit more. (Though perhaps this will be challenging with the open/close pattern employed.)

3/ Are you trying to use `useElements()` inside `ModalSubscriptionForm`? This will conflict with the class component patterns and should be refactored to use the passed `elements`.

Generally I would advise you to simplify your component tree to determine which layer is leading to the failure. Sharing those details here will allow people to help you.

Can you fork & modify the [Code Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-stripe-official-q1loc?) that Stripe shares in the docs to recreate this result using a simplified version of your components?